# how to use gdbus to set an IP address

Tags: command-line, networking, 18.04, network-manager, dbus

I'm researching how to change IP addresses (and DHCP settings) from a workstation app I'm writing which is why I need/want to use dbus for this purpose.

It's complicated! So I'm trying to learn by using gdbus cli.

The approach I've taken is to use gdbus to get the settings for the ethernet adapter I want to modify. Then alter that data and send it back to DBus.

I'm tantalizingly close because the IP address almost changes. I just need to "kick" it by opening the gnome GUI and click on the checkmark for the adapter in question. This causes the settings to take.

I don't know what dbus command clicking that checkmark invokes, but I'm confident that it's the final thing I need to know to be able to use gdbus cli to change IP addresses.

Here's the script I use to set the IP address, I change the `ipv4.addresses`, and `ipv4.address-data` fields so that they specify the same address.

```
#/bin/bash
gdbus call \
    --system \
    --dest org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
    --object-path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1 \
    --method org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection.Update2 \
 "{\
  '802-3-ethernet':\
   {\
    'auto-negotiate': <false>,\
    'mac-address': <[byte 0x00, 0x0c, 0x29, 0x4e, 0x29, 0xe2]>,\
    'mac-address-blacklist': <@as []>,\
    's390-options': <@a{ss} {}>\
  },\
  'connection':\
   {\
    'id': <'Wired connection 1'>,\
    'uuid': <'d075ed7c-c8cc-3db7-b0fb-d0687331a7a0'>,\
    'type': <'802-3-ethernet'>,\
    'permissions': <@as []>,\
    'autoconnect-priority': <-999>,\
    'timestamp': <uint64 1539968649>\
   },\
  'ipv6':\
   {\
    'method': <'ignore'>,\
    'dns': <@aay []>,\
    'dns-search': <@as []>,\
    'addresses': <@a(ayuay) []>,\
    'routes': <@a(ayuayu) []>,\
    'ip6-privacy': <0>,\
    'address-data': <@aa{sv} []>,\
    'route-data': <@aa{sv} []>\
   },\
  'ipv4':\
   {
    'method': <'manual'>,\
    'dns': <[uint32 4261521600]>,\
    'dns-search': <@as []>,\
    'addresses': <[[uint32 3321997504, 24, 16885952]]>,\
    'gateway': <'192.168.1.1'>,
    'routes': <@aau []>,\
    'address-data': <[{'address': <'192.168.1.198'>, 'prefix': <uint32 24>}]>,\
    'route-data': <@aa{sv} []>\
   },\
  'proxy': {}\
 }"\
 1\
 {}
```

And here's what I get when I invoke it...

```
$ ./set.sh
(@a{sv} {},)
```

If I now open the Network Settings GUI, An "in progress" spinning circle appears, and the UI shows the old address. Clicking the checkmark next to the connection name causes the GUI to refresh to show the updated address that I requested.

I also get a ton of monitoring output in a separate terminal that I've set up to report on changes to NetworkManager thus:

```
$ gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop.NetworkManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager
```

If you think the monitoring output would be helpful, I'll paste it into a comment.

So, what's the magic that happens under that checkmark (the one to the right of "Wired connection 1" in the image.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

By running `$ sudo dbus-monitor --system` (N.B. this is a different utility to `gdbus-monitor`) I was able to sniff the traffic on the system dbus.

So I...
1) ran the monitor in one terminal
2) ran my `set.sh` script in another
3) waded thru all the logging in terminal 1 and copied a timestamp at its end.
4) clicked the check mark to activate the connection.
5) copied the timestamp into a text file.
6) select-all in the monitoring terminal and paste into the same text file.
7) searched for the time stamp (among 5000+ lines of logging, no kidding!) to find the dbus command that the click caused, and turned it into the `activate.sh` script that follows.

drum roll....

```
 #!/bin/bash
 gdbus call \
    --system \
    --dest org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
    --object-path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager \
    --method org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.ActivateConnection \
 "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1"\
 "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2"\
 "/"
```

The parameters I'm passing `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1`, and the one that follows can be got from dbus for a specific device, I just hard-coded them for my ethernet adapter once I'd got them.

I can now open the Network Settings GUI and run `set.sh`, followed by `activate.sh` and see the GUI update with the new settings.

I think dbus is cool, but could do with friendlier documentation. Reverse engineering proved much more effective than reading the docs to achieve my ends.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you consult the documentation (https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/spec.html)? Also, there are examples: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/C/glib?id=5eade4da11ee38a0e7faf4a87b2c2b5af07c5eeb

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I spent a lot of time in the spec doc you linked. Also in the NM command reference. As detailed, reference works, neither of these covered use cases (e.g. change IP address, turn DHCP on/off, ...), I also had to grok GVariant’s syntax. You could say I got a good look at the trees but needed a view of the forest.

Comment: link to the aforementioned NM command reference:https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.0/ref-settings.html#id-1.3.3.  I think there's a mistake in the documentation for `ipv4 setting::gateway`. It claims only to be meaningful if the `addresses` property is specified which is in conflict with the description for the `addresses` property and experiment. It works w/o `addresses` being part of the message in other words.